# ATOMでremote-ftpの接続ができない

Tags: atom-editor

Atom, remote-ftp はどちらも最新版です。
connect しようとすると

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:2222

と表示されてます。

再起動しましたが接続されず。

```
{
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 2222,
    "user": "ryji",
  "promptForPass": false,
    "remote": "/",
    "local": "",
    "agent": "",
    "privatekey": "",
    "passphrase": "",
    "hosthash": "",
    "ignorehost": true,
    "connTimeout": 99999,
    "keepalive": 99999,
    "keyboardInteractive": false,
    "keyboardInteractiveForPass": false,
    "remoteCommand": "",
    "remoteShell": "",
    "watch": [],
    "watchTimeout": 500
}
```

このような設定をしています。
どなたか分かる人教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: そのマシンで、SFTPに対応したFTPサーバのプロセスが正常に動作していることを確認していますか？ FTPサーバには、どんなプログラムを使っていますか？

Comment: Fumu 7さん回答ありがとうございます。FTPサーバーのプロセスはどのように確認するのでしょうか？いろいろ調べましたがターミナルを使うので少し心配なので質問させていただきました。virtualboxではホストポート２２２２ゲストポート２２でやっています。プロトコルTCPです。

Comment: 確認ですが、スクリーンショットでは空白になっていますが、実際にはprivatekeyなどに正しい値を設定した.ftpconfigファイルを使っているのですよね？　スクリーンショットに「Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:22」という文字が見えますが、質問には「Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:2222」と書かれています。ポートが22と2222で異なっているのですが、これで正しいのですか？

Comment: 本当にすいません。これは自分のミスです。vurtualboxを起動せずにやっていました。本当に本当にすいません。ありがとうございました。解決しました。

Comment: 解決したのであれば、この質問を「解決済み」にしてください。